# c# - deserialize byte array into different types (including vectors of structs whose length isn't known at compile time) using BinaryPrimitives

Tags: c#, serialization, binary, deserialization

I am trying to work out how to deserialize a byte array from a particular blockchain into a struct in c#.

I have been doing this in javascript using the Beet library (https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/beet) and am trying to replicate similar behaviour in my code.  Looking at some existing libraries (eg https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/blob/master/src/Solnet.Programs/Utilities/Deserialization.cs#L231) they use BinaryPrimitives, so for example to deserialize a u64 they would use:

```
 public static ulong GetU64(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, int offset)
        {
            if (offset + sizeof(ulong) > data.Length)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));
            return BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt64LittleEndian(data.Slice(offset, sizeof(ulong)));
        }
```

And then would for any given struct manually call the relevant functions in turn.  This is ok, but in Beet this is kind of abstracted away, and you just define a list of tuples that maps from parameter name to parameter type, and then the code iterates over that list and does the right thing based on the type specified (so eg I can just say something like ["my_struct", array(MyStruct)] to mean that the data contains an array of MyStructs of unknown length and Beet will deserialize that correctly).

I started trying to do something similar by first defining classes derived from a trivial interface for each data type i'm interested in:
e.g.:

```
public interface DS_t { };

public class DS_u8 : DS_t
{
    static int byteSize = 1;
    static string description = "u8";
    public static byte read(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, int offset)
    {
        if (offset > data.Length - sizeof(byte))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));
        return data[offset];
    }

    public static void write(byte[] data, byte value, int offset)
    {
        if (offset > data.Length - sizeof(byte))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(offset));
        data[offset] = value;
    }

}
```

But at this point I am sort of stuck..
what I want to do is then define something similar to:

```
public struct Sz_Field
{
    public string description;
    public DS_t ds_type;
}

public class Sz_Struct
{
    public Sz_Field[] fields;
}
```

And then, loop through fields calling read/write on each entry, and then initialising the class I am deserializing once I have all the fields.

I've looked at the BinaryReader a bit, but wasn't sure how to handle the case where I have vectors of unknown length of structs that may also have optional fields, whereas at least in Javascript Beet solved that problem, and so I was hoping to just replicate what it did in c#.

Maybe this isn't the right approach, and so i'm happy to hear alternatives, but any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks